# Is there a way to add more than 3 Home Tabs in the Napili Community Template?

Tags: community

The Property Editor shows only 3 fields which correlate to the Home Tabs in the template.  Is there a way to add more?

Answer (score 1):

Standard Napili Template is not supported with any Custom Tabs or Visualforce Page. If you need to include a Visualforce Page, you need to copy the theme and css of Napili Template and implement the same as a Custom Community.

Thanks
Gautam